# Create element and set content with bold text

Tags: jquery, html

Apologies in advance if I am not asking the question properly out of a complete lack of experience in this language.  I have a query that returns weather data (works fine).  All that I want to do is set certain formatting HTML elements such as bold/italic/underline.

In the below piece of code, I would like Location, Conditions and Visibility to be **BOLD**.  Is there a way to do what I want within the code block below?

```
    $('.weather ul').append(
        $('<li />', {
            text: 'Location: ' + Location + ' Conditions: ' + weathernow + ', Visibility: ' + visibility_mi
        })
    );
```

Current Output:  Location: Chicopee, MA Conditions: Clear, Visibility: 10.0m

Desired Output:  **Location:** Chicopee, MA **Conditions:** Clear, **Visibility:** 10.0m

EDIT:  I should have mentioned I have already attempted adding the `<B>` tag in various places where I thought it would go, but it is not working for me.  It shows the `<B>` as if it were text.

Attempt:

```
    $('.weather ul').append(
        $('<li />', {
            text: '<b>Location: </b>' + Location + ' Conditions: ' + weathernow + ', Visibility: ' + visibility_mi
        })
    );
```

Result:
**Location:** Chicopee, MA Conditions: Clear, Visibility: 10.0mi

Comment: You could add a <b> Tag

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_b.asp

Comment: You have to use `html:` instead of `text:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
text: 'Location: ' + Location + ' Conditions: ' + weathernow + ', Visibility: ' + visibility_mi
```

to:

```
html: '<b>Location:</b> ' + Location + ' <b>Conditions:</b> ' + weathernow + ', <b>Visibility:</b> ' + visibility_mi
```

Using `text:`, you cannot add HTML tags. So, as you can see, I've changed it to `html:` and added the `<b>` tags around the text that should show as bold.

Comment: You can also just add the list item directly into the append value https://jsfiddle.net/7uvkq603/

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.